# Jenkins GitHub Organization Metrics

Tags: jenkins, automation, github, metrics

I am using Jenkins with the GitHub Organization item option. On Jenkins with freestyle projects or others I am able to get build metrics: success, failure,  date, node and so forth.

On the GitHub Organization item, these metrics do not ever populate. I am looking for an automated way to generate these reports. I am hoping for a Jenkins plugin solution or Splunk for Jenkins.

It is an issue with GitHub single webhook and non physical Jenkins jobs.

Comment: Please add a report template and indicate how often the report should be generated.